# Why do I have to "from module import" with the email module in python?

Tags: python, email, import, attributes, smtplib

Sorry if the question isn't spot on, I'm having difficulty phrasing this question properly.

I'm trying to use the email module to create a simple plain text email and send it when certain conditions are met.  I'm running in to all sorts of abnormal behavior and would like to understand it.  I started with a simple test pulled from the official examples (https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html) and it worked fine.  When I started trying to implement this in my project I started getting all sorts of `"'module' object has no attribute 'something'"`.  I can run something like this and it works fine

```
import email
import smtplib

# Create message object
msg = email.message.EmailMessage()

# Create the from and to Addresses
from_address = email.headerregistry.Address("Stack of Pancakes", "pancakes@gmail.com") 
to_address = email.headerregistry.Address("Joe", "pythontest@mailinator.com")

# Create email headers
msg['Subject'] = "subject of email"
msg['From'] = from_address
msg['To'] = to_address

#
email_content = "This is a plain text email"
msg.set_content(email_content)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("pancakes@gmail.com", "password")
server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

This works perfectly.  However if I order things differently things start breaking and I don't understand why.  For example if I place the `from_address` and `to_address` lines above where the EmailMessage is called like so

```
import email
import smtplib

# Create the from and to Addresses
from_address = email.headerregistry.Address("Stack of Pancakes", "pancakes@gmail.com") 
to_address = email.headerregistry.Address("Joe", "pythontest@mailinator.com")

# Create message object
msg = email.message.EmailMessage()

... other code
```

It fails with `'module' object has no attribute 'headerregistry'`.  Why does the EmailMessage creation allow the other code to function properly?

In fact if I have a file that contains only this

```
import email

to_address = email.headerregistry.Address("joe", "joe@joe.com")
```

it fails with the same error.

To get that small snippet to run I had to do this

```
from email.headerregistry import Address

to_address = Address("joe", "joe@joe.com")
```

Alternatively, and this is really weird, I can get this to run

```
import email
import smtplib

email.message.EmailMessage()
to_address = email.headerregistry.Address("joe", "joe@joe.com")
```

but if I remove the `import smtplib` it starts failing again, even though I haven't used anything in smtplib in those 4 lines.

---

I'm fairly certain I can just keep trying every combination I can think of and get it to work properly, but I'd prefer to understand the behavior.  That way I would feel more confident running the code in a production environment.

Why can't I just call `import email` and declare my objects with `email.headderregistry.Address`, why do I have to explicitly import that specific function with `from email.headerregistry import Address`?  Why did it compile with `import smtplib` but failed without it.  Why does it work only after `EmailMessage()` is called?

Normally I'm really good about finding answers, but I think in this situation I just don't know what to search for.  There are a whole bunch of solutions to the "module object has no attribute", but most of them were duplicate named files, circular imports, calling functions that didn't exist or checking if an attribute exists.  None of them seemed to address how import behavior worked.  Am I structuring the code wrong or is the email module just acting up on me?

Comment: is your script named `email.py`? :)  I've been tripped up with that one before, naming my module after a system module.

Comment: You may have made a small cut and paste error somewhere because your original code block does not work as stated. It needs to have `from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.headerregistry import Address`

Comment: @shavenwarthog Nope, I addressed that in my last paragraph.

Comment: @VidhyaG Nope, works perfectly for me.  Just have to use a real gmail login on the 3rd to last line.  Even checked the mailinator page and it was indeed delivered.  Not sure why it wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Sorry. Yes my bad.  You are using a module (email.headerregistry) that has been introduced in Python 3.3 and is provisional http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0411/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`import email` will not automatically import all the modules inside the `email` package. This means that, in order to use `email.headerregistry`, you must import it, which can be as simple as:

```
import email.headerregistry
```

After that you'll be able to use `email.headerregistry.Address`.

Your code also works after writing `from email.headerregistry import Address` because that statement internally does the (equivalent of) `import email.headerregistry` in order to load the module and get hold of `Address`. Likewise, `smtplib` imports `email`-related modules, some of which likely imports `email.headerregistry`.

To summarize: once **any module** performs the import of `email.headerregistry`, that submodule becomes visible to **all modules** that imported `email`, even if they never explicitly requested `email.headerregistry`. The fact that importing a module can make submodules of an unrelated package available as a side effect can lead to nasty bugs where a module works only if imported after some other modules. Fortunately, modern tools like pylint and Eclipse's pydev are good at fixing this kind of pitfall.

Comment: This addresses most of the problems.  Any idea why it would fail when you try to call `email.headderregistry.Address` before `email.message.EmailMessage()`, but worked fine if you called `EmailMessage()` first?

Comment: @StackofPancakes I would expect that instantiating `EmailMessage` for the first time causes import of `email.headerregistry`.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I've encountered a module that behaved so weirdly after just using `import module_name`.  I guess in the future I'll go straight to importing specific sections of a module if I encounter this situation again.

Comment: @StackofPancakes I agree it's surprising, but it's normally considered a feature that `import package` doesn't necessarily import all subpackages — after all, some packages can be really large. The **really** surprising thing is that you get the submodules even if you **don't** import them, as long as someone else imports the submodule before you try to access it.